# Chef with AWS with Local machine as Workstation - Private Subnet Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, devops, subnet

I am using [chef-provisioning-aws](https://github.com/chef/chef-provisioning-aws) library to configure AWS machines from my local machines as the Workstation.

But I am facing problems creating machines in private subnets.  As soon as the machine is created, the chef client running on my local machine tries to SSH into the instance in private subnet.  This action fails as the machine is meant to be a private subnet.

The library I am using does not provide any features to deal with this situation.

Is there a workaround for this problem?  Are there any alternative solutions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is, for the most part, outside of the design scope of `chef-provisioning` as it stands today. The best workaround would probably be to run your provisioning node on an EC2 instance attached to a management subnet that has routes to all other subnets, including internal ones. I would recommend looking at tools other than `chef-provisioning` given the requirements you have stated, but it's close enough that you can probably make it work :)

Comment: Thanks @coderanger, Any other Chef based AWS tools you know that can help?  `chef-provisioning-aws` is quite a pain to use.

Comment: No, there are no Chef-based generic provisioning tools at this time. I would look in to CloudFormation and Terraform.

Comment: Thanks @coderanger, I will wait for some more answers  before accepting yours  :)

Comment: I'm working on a public statement about this, will probably go up Monday. I can assure that fact that you should probably not use chef-provisioning isn't something you can get a second opinion on.